# React Native Firebase - Push data to Array allowing to display in a FlatList

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to React Native and struggling a little to get this working.  I have realtime database in Firebase which contains 'mechanic' names.  I would like to retrieve these names and display them in a list.

[image]

I would like to display this data in a list and then execute some function when the user clicks on either name.  I thought adding the database data to an array then looping through the array to add it to my FlatList.

The problem now is that when I execute the code, the `this.setState({ mechanicsList: mechanicsTemp });` returns an error.

**Error**

```
[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: this.setState is not a function. 

(In 'this.setState({]
* src\screens\FindMechanics.js:28:30 in <unknown>
- node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:37:14 in tryCallOne
- node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:123:25 in <unknown>
- ... 8 more stack frames from framework internals
```

**Full Code**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, SafeAreaView, TouchableOpacity, ScrollView, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import { Card } from 'react-native-elements'
import firebase from "firebase/app";

export default class FindMechanics extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            mechanicsList: [],
            isDataLoaded: false
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        var query = firebase.database().ref("MechanicList").orderByKey();
        query.once("value")
            .then(function (snapshot) {
                let mechanicsTemp = [];
                snapshot.forEach(function (childSnapshot) {
                    // key will be the auth ID for each user
                    var key = childSnapshot.key;
                    var mechanicName = snapshot.child(key + '/name').val();
                    mechanicsTemp.push({ _name: mechanicName, _key: key });
                });           
                mechanicsList = mechanicsTemp;            
                () => this.setState({ mechanicsList: mechanicsTemp }); // This does not execute it seems - main problem I believe
                //this.setState({ mechanicsList: mechanicsTemp }); - This return a warning 'this.setState is not a function'
                console.log(mechanicsList); //Prints data as expected
                mechanicsTemp.forEach((mechanic) => {
                   console.log( mechanic._name); //Prints data as expected
                });
            });
    }

    render() {
        //The Card element is empty - nothing shows. 
        console.log(this.state.mechanicsList) //This return Array [] which indicates it is empty
        return (
            <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
                <ScrollView horizontal={true}>
                    <TouchableOpacity>
                        <Card style={styles.card}>
                            {
                                this.state.mechanicsList.map((u, i) => {
                                    return (
                                        <View key={i}>
                                            <Text>{u._key}</Text>
                                            <Text>{u._name}</Text>
                                        </View>
                                    );
                                })
                            }
                        </Card>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </ScrollView>
            </SafeAreaView>
        )
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#FFF'
    },
    paragraph: {
        margin: 24,
        fontSize: 18,
        textAlign: 'center',
    },
    card: {
        flex: 1,
        width: '80%',
    },
});
```

**Console**

```
Finished building JavaScript bundle in 384ms.
Running application on Android SDK built for x86.
Array []
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1st thing, you have `mechanics` object in state so you need to access it like

```
console.log(this.state.mechanics)
```

2nd thing is that you are not updating state variable when you are having data, it should be like following

```
let mechanicsTemp = [];
snapshot.forEach(function (childSnapshot) {
    // key will be the auth ID for each user
    var key = childSnapshot.key;
    var mechanicName = snapshot.child(key + '/name').val();
    mechanicsTemp.push({_name: mechanicName, _key: key});
});

this.setState({ mechanics:mechanicsTemp })
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  When I try the above, I now get Array [] printed in my console rather than undefined. I updated the code above in the description.

Comment: you forgot to change variable name while pushing data, it should be `mechanicsTemp `

Comment: Ah yes, my mistake - sorry! Weirdly even after that change I get the same result: Array [].  I cannot see anything else I may have forgot..I updated the code above again.

Comment: I believe debugging it can help you more. Have some logs when you have data, try to log `mechanicsTemp ` also.

Comment: No worries - I'll give it a shot and hopefully get it sorted.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Hiya - sorry to be bothering you now.  I amended the code above with what I tried so far and some info I found out after debugging.  The main problem I believe now is just the this.setState is throwing a warning to say setState is not a function - which is weird.  Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I dunno if you still need help with this or not but I just used your code and I solved this.setState problem with binding. You can either use arrow function or bind your function:

```
.then(function (snapshot) {
// ..
}.bind(this));
```